# Parsing Contentful Webhooks (Custom JSON types)

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, webhooks, contentful

I'm currently using this Contentful-webhook-server to listen for webhooks when content is unpublished.

```
    server.listen(30000, function(){
  console.log('Contentful webhook server running on port ' + 30000)
});

server.on('ContentManagement.Entry.publish', function(req){
  console.log('An entry was published!', req);
});

server.on('ContentManagement.Entry.unpublish', function(req){
  console.log('An entry was unpublished!');
  console.log('Deleted SOLR ID: ', req);
});
```

I'm trying to parse the response I've got but I can't seem to find a way to parse the custom JSON they use in their response. Should I be creating my own server with express or am I missing a way to get the response body in this example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contentful-webhook-server` library uses the plain node `http` module for the server. Thus, the `req` object is a readable stream that you need to buffer and parse to get the body.

Take a look at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body for an example.